# How to print all lines after a match up to the end of the file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

Input file1 is:

```
dog 123 4335
cat 13123 23424 
deer 2131 213132
bear 2313 21313
```

I give the match the  pattern from in `other file` ( like `dog 123 4335` from   file2).

I match the pattern of the line is `dog 123 4335` and after printing
all lines without match line my output is:

```
cat 13123 23424
deer 2131 213132
bear 2313 21313
```

If only use without address of line only use the pattern, for example `1s`
how to  match and  print the lines?

Comment: Can other file contain just a single pattern to search for, or one per line, and start searching at whichever line is found first in the searched file?

Answer (score 67):

In practice, I'd probably use [Aet3miirah's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56429/how-to-print-all-lines-after-a-match-up-to-the-end-of-the-file/140314#140314) most of the time, and [alexey's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56429/how-to-print-all-lines-after-a-match-up-to-the-end-of-the-file/77650#77650) is wonderful for navigating through the lines (also, it works with `less`). OTOH, I really like another approach (which is kind of the reversed [Gilles' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56429/how-to-print-all-lines-after-a-match-up-to-the-end-of-the-file/56517#56517)):

```
sed -n '/dog 123 4335/,$p'
```

When called with the `-n` flag, `sed` does not print by default the lines it processes anymore. Then we use a 2-address form that says to apply a command from the line matching `/dog 123 4335/` until the end of the file (represented by `$`). The command in question is `p`, which prints the current line. So, this means "print all lines from the one matching `/dog 123 4335/` until the end."

Comment: That prints the `dog` line though which is not wanted here.

Comment: This looks like the best answer (and works for my own case) but would need to be adapted to skip the matched line as well.

Comment: sed -n '/dog 123 4335/,$p' | sed '1d' will remove the dog line

Comment: `sed -n '/dog 123 4335/,$p' | tail -n +2` will remove the match as well

Comment: Quick note: `-n` for don't-print-processed-lines, 
`/pattern/` inside forward-slash `/`, 
`$` for end, 
`p` for print

Comment: If you want to stop at another pattern, use `sed -n '/start/,/end/p'`. It works like a charm, thanks for the explaination!

Answer (score 42):

If you have a reasonably short file `grep` alone might work:

```
grep -A5000 -m1 -e 'dog 123 4335' animals.txt
```

5000 is just my guess at "reasonably short", as `grep` finds the first match and outputs it together with the next 5000 lines (the file doesn't need to have that many). If you don't want the match itself you'll need to cut it off, e.g.

```
grep -A5000 -m1 -e 'dog 123 4335' animals.txt | tail -n+2
```

---

If you do not want the first, but the last match as delimiter you could use this:

```
tac animals.txt | sed -e '/dog 123 4335/q' | tac
```

This line reads `animals.txt` in reverse order of lines and outputs up to and including the line with `dog 123 4335` and then reverses again to restore proper order.

Again, if you don't need the match in the result, append tail. (You could also complicate the sed expression to discard its buffer before quitting.)

Comment: By my test, GNU grep 3.0 doesn't output more than 132 lines in after-context (regardless of specified value).

Comment: Mine seems to max out at 1000 lines.  Doesn't work at all in OS X.  But at least it's more comprehensible :)

Answer (score 38):

Assuming you want to match the whole line with your pattern, with GNU `sed`, this works:

```
sed -n '/^dog 123 4335$/ { :a; n; p; ba; }' infile
```

Standard equivalent:

```
sed -ne '/^dog 123 4335$/{:a' -e 'n;p;ba' -e '}' infile
```

With the following input (`infile`):

```
cat 13123 23424 
deer 2131 213132
bear 2313 21313
dog 123 4335
cat 13123 23424 
deer 2131 213132
bear 2313 21313
```

The output is:

```
cat 13123 23424 
deer 2131 213132
bear 2313 21313
```

#### Explanation:

- `/^dog 123 4335$/` searches for the desired pattern.
- `:a; n; p; ba;` is a loop that fetches a new line from input (`n`), prints it (`p`), and branches back to label a `:a; ...; ba;`.

#### Update

Here's an answer that comes closer to your needs, i.e. pattern in file2, grepping from file1:

```
tail -n +$(( 1 + $(grep -m1 -n -f file2 file1 | cut -d: -f1) )) file1
```

The embedded grep and cut find  the first line containing a pattern from file2, this line number plus one is passed on to tail, the plus one is there to skip the line with the pattern.

If you want to start from the last match instead of the first match it would be:

```
tail -n +$(( 1 + $(grep -n -f file2 file1 | tail -n1 | cut -d: -f1) )) file1
```

Note that not all versions of tail support the plus-notation.

Comment: This is the first example of the n and p commands in sed that I have seen that doesn't feel like taking sed too far.  It seems (from my brief tests) that `sed -n '/^dog 123 4335$/ { :a; p; n; ba; }' infile` (with the p and n switched) successfully includes the line that matches as well.

Answer (score 18):

```
sed -e '1,/dog 123 4335/d' file1
```

If you need to read the pattern from a file, substitute it into the sed command. If the file contains a sed pattern:

```
sed -e "1,/$(cat file2)/d" file1
```

If the file contains a literal string to look for, quote all special characters. I assume the file contains a single line.

```
sed -e "1,/$(sed 's/[][\\\/^$.*]/\\&/g' file2)/d" file1
```

If you want the match to be the whole line, not just a substring, wrap the pattern in `^…$`.

```
sed -e "1,/^$(sed 's/[][\\\/^$.*]/\\&/g' file2)\$/d" file1
```

Comment: That won't work if the pattern is on the first line. GNU `sed` has `0,/dog.../d` for that.

Answer (score 18):

`$  more +/"dog 123 4335" file1`

Comment: It also works with `less`.

Comment: clever on the terminal, but it doesn't actually work if you pipe it into something else like `tac`.

Comment: i am using it like this , $ more +/"match my words" file1 >> file2

Comment: Maybe `+` was replaced by `-p` in POSIX 7: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/more.html but not yet implemented in util-linux 2.20.1. And this also prints `skipping..` and some extra newlines (to stderr I expect, so might be fine).

Comment: maybe things have changed since then? my comment got 3 upvotes so it may have been relevant at the time...

Comment: This works really well -- but be careful to escape the search string as `more` passes it to `grep`, and if it fails outputs from the start of the file anyway.

Answer (score 11):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {getline pattern < "other file"}
   NR == 1, $0 ~ pattern {next}; {print}' < "input file"
```

Answer (score 7):

My answer for the question in the subject, without storing pattern in a second file.
Here is my test file:

```
$ cat animals.txt 
cat 13123 23424 
deer 2131 213132
bear 2313 21313
dog 123 4335
cat 13123 23424 
deer 2131 213132
bear 2313 21313
```

GNU sed:

```
 $ sed '0,/^dog 123 4335$/d' animals.txt 
 cat 13123 23424 
 deer 2131 213132
 bear 2313 21313
```

Perl:

```
$ perl -ne 'print unless 1.../^dog 123 4335$/' animals.txt
cat 13123 23424 
deer 2131 213132
bear 2313 21313
```

Perl variant with pattern in a file:

```
$ cat pattern.txt 
dog 123 4335
$ perl -ne 'BEGIN{chomp($p=(<STDIN>)[0])};print unless 1../$p/;' animals.txt < pattern.txt
cat 13123 23424 
deer 2131 213132
bear 2313 21313
```

Comment: May I ask what is `1...` in the first Perl variant? How is it different from the second's `1..`?

Answer (score 5):

One way using awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}f;($0 in a){f=1}'  file2 file1
```

where file2 contains your search patterns. First, all the contents of file2 are stored in the array "a". When the file1 is processed, every line is checked against the array, and printed only if is not present.

Comment: I think the OP wants to output every line following the pattern.

Comment: @Thor : thanks for pointing it out, updated it now...

Comment: Nicely done :).

Answer (score 5):

If the input is an *lseekable* regular file:

With GNU `grep`:

```
{ grep  -xFm1 'dog 123 4335' >&2
  cat; } <infile 2>/dev/null >outfile
```

With `sed`:

```
{ sed -n '/^dog 123 4335$/q'
  cat; } <infile >outfile
```

A GNU `grep` called w/ the `-m` option will quit input at the match - and it will leave its *(lseekable)* input fd immediately after the point it found its last match. So calling `grep` w/ `-m1` finds the first occurrence of a pattern in a file, and leaves the input offset at precisely the right place for `cat` to write everything following the pattern's first match in a file to stdout.

Even without a GNU `grep` you can do the exact same thing w/ a POSIX compatible `sed` - when `sed` `q`uits it is specified to leave its input offset right where it does. GNU `sed` is not standards-compliant in this way, though, and so the above will likely not work w/ a GNU `sed` unless you call it with its `-u` switch.

Comment: note, the `sed` stream sharing demonstrated here is not *specially* (though, yes, the standard referenced does specifically example `sed` as a utility thus capable) of the free-form and conditionally cooperative workflow shown.  notably, ***all standard utilities*** are meant and specified to thus cooperate and share cursor positions of input streams without failing the next reader any processing at all. `grep -q` should do this; quietly `grep` should return as soon as any match in input is found, and any remaining of input should not, by standard, be consumed by default.

Answer (score 5):

Wth `ed`:

```
ed -s file1 <<< '/dog 123 4335/+1,$p'
```

This sends one `p`rint command to ed in a here-string; the print command is limited in range to one *after* (`+1`) the `dog 123 4335` match until the end of the file (`$`).

Comment: Probably the most universal answer here because ed is available on just about every Unix in existence.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the creation of a temporary file, and have `csplit` available, this works:

```
sh -c 'csplit -sf"$1_" "$1" "%^$(cat "$2")%+1" && cat "${1}_00"' sh file1 file2
```

Note `file1` is the input file and `file2` is the pattern file (as stated in the question).

The long form of the above command is:

```
sh -c 'csplit --quiet --prefix="$1_" "$1" "%^$(cat "$2")%+1" && cat "${1}_00"' sh file1 file2
```

i.e.,

```
csplit --quiet --prefix="file1_" "file1" "%^$(cat "file2")%+1" && cat "file1_00"
```

`csplit` without the `prefix` flag above would create the file `xx00` (prefix being `xx`, and suffix being `00`). With the flag above it creates the file `file1_00`. Without the `quiet` flag, it prints the output file size (size of the resulting file).

Answer (score 0):

Since awk isn't expressly disallowed, here's my offering assuming 'cat' is the match.

```
awk '$0 ~ /cat/ { vart = NR }{ arr[NR]=$0 } END { for (i = vart; i<=NR ; i++) print arr[i]  }' animals.txt
```